# Nested List weight sum javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, array-algorithms

I'm trying to work on this problem where we compute Nested weight sum for a given array of numbers.

> Given a nested list of integers, return the sum of all integers in the
> list weighted by their depth.

For example for:

> [[1,1],2,[1,1]]  ====>  solution is 10.
>
> Four 1's at depth 2, one 2 at depth 1.

Here's the code i wrote:

```
var depthSum = function (nestedList, sum=0, depth=1) {
    for(let i=0; i<nestedList.length; i++){
        let val = nestedList[i];
        if (Array.isArray(val)) {
            return depthSum(val, sum, depth+1);
        } else {
            sum += val * depth;
        }
    };
    return sum;
};
```

I'm trying to work on the converse problem. i.e

> Given a nested list of integers, return the sum of all integers in the
> list weighted by their depth. Where weight is increasing from root to
> leaf, now the weight is defined from bottom up. i.e., the leaf level
> integers have weight 1, and the root level integers have the largest
> weight.

Example:
[[1,1],2,[1,1]] ===> Solution is 8.

How can I use the same approach and solve this problem?

(https://leetcode.com/problems/nested-list-weight-sum-ii/description/)

Comment: I'd traverse to find the max depth and then apply your previous algorithm in a second traversal. The link is for premium members only.

Comment: Thanks for the input ggorlen, can you enlighten me on how it works? Should i do like a DFS on array and find max depth first?

Comment: It's not really a DFS or BFS because you'd have to search the entire structure, so any full traversal will do. I'll post some code, but I can't validate it on your link.

Comment: ggorlen is right. It needs two traversals - one to find max depth and then one to calculate the result. A queue based BFS would do for both.

Comment: You don't need two traversals if you keep a list of the totals per level, and then multiply them by their depth after the traversal.

Answer (score 2):

This *should* do the job, but I wish I had a premium leetcode account to verify that. The idea is to do a search to find the maximum depth in the structure, then use your previous algorithm but with the depth calculation inverted. Also, doing it without recursion means less chance of timing out and no chance of blowing the stack. I added a few basic test cases, but again, no guarantees.

```js
const search = a => {
  let sum = 0;
  let depth = 0;
  const stack = [[a, 0]];

  while (stack.length) {
    const curr = stack.pop();

    if (curr[1] > depth) {
      depth = curr[1];
    }

    for (const e of curr[0]) {
      if (Array.isArray(e)) {
        stack.push([e, curr[1] + 1]);
      }
    }
  }

  stack.push([a, ++depth]);

  while (stack.length) {
    const curr = stack.pop();

    for (const e of curr[0]) {
      if (Array.isArray(e)) {
        stack.push([e, curr[1] - 1]);
      }
      else {
        sum += e * curr[1];
      }
    }
  }

  return sum;
};

console.log(search([[1,1],2,[1,1]]));
console.log(search([]));
console.log(search([6]));
console.log(search([[[[3]]]]));
console.log(search([[2],1]));
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this awesome piece. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

A basic recursive solution alone like your original `depthSum` probably won't work for the second requirement, because you need to figure out the total depth before you know the multiplier for the items on the top level of the array. One option is to figure out the depth of the deepest array first, and then use something similar to your original `depthSum`.

You can use `reduce` (which is the appropriate method to use to convert an object into a single value) and the conditional (ternary) operator to make your code concise and less repetitive:

```js
const depthCheck = (item) => (
  Array.isArray(item)
  ? 1 + Math.max(...item.map(depthCheck))
  : 0
);

// verification:
console.log(depthCheck([[1,1],2,[1,1]])); // total depth 2
console.log(depthCheck([[1,1],2,[1,1,[2,2]]])) // total depth 3
console.log(depthCheck([[1,1,[2,[3,3]]],2,[1,1,[2,2]]])) // total depth 4
console.log('-----')

const depthSum = (nestedList, weight=depthCheck(nestedList)) => (
  nestedList.reduce((a, val) => a + (
    Array.isArray(val)
    ? depthSum(val, weight - 1)
    : val * weight
  ), 0)
);

console.log(depthSum([[1,1],2,[1,1]])) // (2)*2 + (1+1+1+1)*1
console.log(depthSum([[1,1],2,[1,1,[2,2]]])) // (2)*3 + (1+1+1+1)*2 + (2+2)*1
console.log(depthSum([[1,1,[2,[3,3]]],2,[1,1,[2,2]]])) // (2)*4 + (1+1+1+1)*3 + (2)*2 + (3+3)*1
```

Comment: What an amazing solution. Thank you so much. Will go through it in depth!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without needing two traversals of the nested array, if you store the sums of the elements per depth in an array during the traversal. Afterwards, you know that the length of this array is the maximum depth, and you can multiply the sums by their correct weight.

The traversal can be done using recursion or a stack, as explained in the other answers. Here's an example using recursion:

```js
function weightedSum(array) {
    var sums = [], total = 0;
    traverse(array, 0);
    for (var i in sums)
        total += sums[i] * (sums.length - i);
    return total;

    function traverse(array, depth) {
        if (sums[depth] === undefined)
            sums[depth] = 0;
        for (var i in array) {
            if (typeof array[i] === "number")
                sums[depth] += array[i];
            else traverse(array[i], depth + 1);
        }
    }
}

console.log(weightedSum([[],[]]));
console.log(weightedSum([[1,1],2,[1,1]]));
console.log(weightedSum([1,[[],2,2],1,[[3,3,[[5]]],[3]],[]]));
```

Answer (score -1):

May be you can do as follows with a simple recursive reducer.

```js
var weightOfNested = (a,d=1) => a.reduce((w,e) => Array.isArray(e) ? w + weightOfNested(e,d+1)
                                                                   : w + d*e, 0);
console.log(weightOfNested([[1,1,[3]],2,[1,1]]));
```

So OK as mentioned in the comment the above code is weighing the deeper elements more. In order to weigh the shallow ones more we need to know the depth of the array in advance. I believe this way or that way you end up traversing the array twice... once for the depth and once for calculating the weighted sum.

```js
var weightOfNested = (a, d = getDepth(a)) => a.reduce((w,e) => Array.isArray(e) ? w + weightOfNested(e,d-1)
                                                                                : w + d*e, 0),
    getDepth       = (a, d = 1, t = 1) => a.reduce((r,e) => Array.isArray(e) ? r === t ? getDepth(e,++r,t+1)
                                                                                       : getDepth(e,r,t+1)
                                                                             : r, d);
console.log(weightOfNested([[1,1,[3]],2,[1,1]])); // depth is 3
```

Comment: I think this solves the basic version, not the reverse weight version.

Comment: @m69 Yes right.. Thanks for the heads up.. I have added a proper approach. Your solution though, is also traversing around the same number of times is what i think.

Comment: Well, the input array is always longer and/or higher-dimensional than the sums array, so I assume it'll be faster in practice, even if the theoretical time complexity for all approaches is O(N).